# how to ignore buffer-read-only when archiving subtrees in org mode?

Tags: org-mode, file-local-variables

In my org-mode archive files, I like having `buffer-read-only` set as a file-local variable so that if I open the archive to find something, I don't accidentally mess anything up. It seems to be in the right spirit for something called an "archive".

But with something like `-*- buffer-read-only: t; -*-`, when I use `org-archive-subtree` or similar, it fails because the buffer is read-only, of course.

I'd like the archiving commands to ignore that, while keeping the buffer read-only when I visit it normally.

I could advise `org-archive-subtree`, and set `inhibit-read-only` before the function is called, and reset it afterwards. But there's all kinds of (regular) advice that says [emacs lisp advice is a last resort, should be avoided, etc](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Advice), although here that seems not so risky, something like:

```
(advice-add
 'org-archive-subtree
 :before
 (lambda (&rest r)
   (message "Inhibiting buffer-read-only before archiving subtree...")
   (setq inhibit-read-only t)))

(advice-add
 'org-archive-subtree
 :after
 (lambda (&rest r)
   (message "Clearing inhibit-read-only after archiving subtree.")
   (setq inhibit-read-only nil)))
```

If I want to take that advice about advice, how could I make the archiving commands ignore `buffer-read-only`, while preserving it when I visit the file as usual? There's only one hook related to archiving, and that runs *after*.

Comment: One interesting note: in a read-only archive file, if I use `org-store-link`, it will ignore `buffer-read-only` and create a PROPERTIES drawer to make an ID property. It seems strange that store-link by default (?) seems to ignore `buffer-read-only` but archiving doesn't.

Comment: `org-store-link` does not add an ID property by default: try it with `emacs -Q`.

Comment: All that the linked (regular) advice says IMO is: use  a hook to modify the behavior *if* one exists; use `advice` otherwise. That assumes that you have thought about the consequences of changing behavior (something that you should always do of course - all such changes introduce incompatibilities between your setup and the default one, so they should be done sparingly and documented copiously), but if you need the change, then using `advice` is perfectly reasonable IMO.

Comment: (1) my idiosyncratic configuration for `org-store-link` does add an ID property; I should go see how/why it ignores `buffer-read-only`; (2) your comment about using hooks when available is what I settled on. There's `org-archive-hook `, but that runs after, and I would need both before and after hooks.